# How to check if postgres server is up through Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-connection

I am trying to create a health check page for my app. There are 3 different servers for back end, front end and database.
I have created an API to check if services (sidekiq, redis) are running.
Now, I want to check if postgres server is up or not.
For this I have added a method

`def database?
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.active?
end`

This method returns true when postgres is running. If the Postgres server is stopped, and I try to hit my API I get

`PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
):`

How to rescue this error?

Comment: I don't think you can do that though the rails app since it tries to connect to the db first. You'll have to be on an app that has no db requirement which pings certain services such as db, redis, sidekiq. Redis, sidekiq you can easily do from the rails app but db, nope. Maybe someone know more :).

Comment: @razvans, Thanks. Could you please guide me what is the standard way to check db connections? Or can you elaborate more on app with no db requirement.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent rails guts to be loaded before you actually check the DB connection, I would suggest to create a simple rack middleware, and put in the very beginning of middlewares stack:

```
class StatusMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    return @app.call(env) unless status_request?(env)

    # Feel free to respond with JS here if needed
    if database_alive?
      [200, {}, []]
    else
      [503, {}, []]
    end
  end

  private

  def status_request?(env)
    # Change the route to whatever you like
    env['PATH_INFO'] == '/postgres_status' && env['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'
  end

  def database_alive?
    ::ActiveRecord::Base.connection.verify!
    true
  rescue StandardError
    false
  end
end
```

And in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, StatusMiddleware
```

Comment: If Postgres server is not running, then the request doesn't reach to the controller, and `PG::ConnectionBad` error is thrown. So the rescue mentioned will not work.

Comment: @nattfodd But when you enter a "system health" page which eventually uses that method, won't it crash? It would.

Comment: you are right, I've changed the answer, check it out

Comment: @nattfodd. Yes! This is working properly. Will check for other services as well. Thank you!

Comment: @PrajaktaC don't forget to select the correct answer once you're done

Comment: @nattfodd.. Tried upvoting your answer but currently short of reputation score to select the correct answer as 15 points are needed. Will do that once I reach to 15.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything like it but here's how I'd do it.

Host a rails app (or sinatra, with no db or a dummy one) to `status.myapp.com` which is just a simple index page with a bunch of checks - db, redis, sidekiq. I'd make sure is hosted on the same machine as the production one.

1. `db` - try to establish a connection to your production db - fails or not
2. `redis` - try to see if it's a running process for `redis-server`
3. `sidekiq` - try to see if it's a running process for `sidekiq`
4. `etc ...`

Again, just an idea. Maybe someone did it differently.